# Annoying "[Environment: Sandbox]" alert

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, storekit

While testing beta versions of our iOS apps we've been recently seeing an alert with the following text only "[Environment: Sandbox]"

My guess is that this is a bug in the app store process but I don't know for sure.

Has anyone encountered the issue? 
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Many people are seeing the same issue today.

Comment: Did you use any apple API, Like StoreKit etc. We had this Sandbox message on alert shown from StoreKit while in debug mode.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Update: Most probably a temporary Apple glitch. Our customers start calling, reporting this problem as well.

### Update 2: Seems to be fixed now.

[image]

This started happening all of the sudden earlier today. The weird thing is that we are using an AdHoc/Enterprise build in which we can't use the IAPs. To me this looks a bit like a server/time-related issue on Apple's side. Weird. The weirdest thing is that the app is a "production" build, not a debug build.

I suspect this is a temporary thing as it suddenly started happening and (hopefully) will go away again.

Interestingly an older production build that worked fine before, suddenly starts displaying this alert all the time whenever it starts. I can reproduce this on all my devices, so it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the build itself.

As soon as I log out of the "iTunes and App Store" panel in system settings, this stops happening. So I suspect there is something going on with the App Store/iTunes infrastructure.

Comment: Seeing the same issue with a live App Store build.

Comment: @Kamchatka: I guess it will be the same case here. Just wait and see if it will go away. Otherwise try rebooting the device and see if that helps. Definitely was an Apple issue originally.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem, I think its just an alert to let you know that you're signed in with a real AppleID account but you are using the sandbox app store, and so can't purchase anything.

You can fix it by signing out of your current AppleID account (Settings > iTunes & App Store > Click on your AppleID > Sign Out).

Comment: Nope. This alert occurred on my new device with which I had never once logged into the sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

I had this as well all day long. According to the thread on the Apple forum (https://devforums.apple.com/message/800016#800016), it should be fixed now.

> OK, we've made an update on the server which should fix this issue.  Please post here if you're still seeing a problem with this empty alert coming up.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same at our app. Seems it comes from the call:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

When I delete the line the alert is not shown.

Comment: And what if you need in app purchases? this is kind of absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Another confirmation, this has to be a temporary apple bug, my existing apps started to produce the same, also my current project in which I disabled all Storekit functionalities and now it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've an idea it might be to do with TestFlightApp, if all of you are using that.

Comment: Already checked that, even with TF disabled this keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

We only get this alert for apps with release configuration, that are IAP-ready - that means, they link the StoreKit.framework and have registered a transaction observer to the default payment queue - but do not have a IAP-product set up in iTunesConnect. Simply setting one up should be a temporary solution for App Store apps. Of course, this is no option for enterprise apps.

Some users are already complaining in the Apple Support Communities about this problem https://discussions.apple.com/message/21696486?searchText=environment%20sandbox#21696486

So we can expect Apple will fix this problem within the next hours/days.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround for us has been to put the device in airplane mode, or log out of the store.  Airplane mode seems easier for testers than logging out and back in, but may interfere with other things.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is because of invalid test user account. Just create a test user account in itunesconnect and login using that account in device. It will fix the issue. **It happens, when you use inAppPurchase without a valid test user account.**

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Airplane mode is fine solution, but not permanent. If you can't do anything with your device, even turn on the Airplane mode, try to lock your device and then turn on the Airplane mode. Unlock your device and stay in Airplane mode for a couple of minutes. Then once turned off, the message will disappear for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going into Setting -> Celluar Data and disabling access to whichever app you suspect is causing this.  This is a better solution than Airplane mode because it at least allows you to access your other applications with little interruption.  You just have to stay off of wifi.

Answer (score -4):

First,log out game center.
And then use ifundbox or itools to enter this address: /var/mobile/Library/Caches/
Find this file and backup: com.apple.mobile.installation.plist

copy it to your PC and delete these code:

```
<key>ProfileValidated</key>
<true/>
<key>SignerIdentity</key>
<string>TDMTANF Bypass</string>
```

And then replace this file.

Log on game center,and everything recovered.

By the way:All of you are **the 5.1.1 version**,right?

Comment: iOS 6.1.2 here. What has GameCenter to do with this?